# Store a List<Proxy> to a user's db account in Asp.net MVC C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, proxy, entity

I am trying to store a list of Proxies into a user's account in the database.

I am using entity to store information. I know that I could go about it having a property nvarchar(max) in my db. then add a string containing the proxy information per user's account. Then when I need to read those I could split every Proxy '|' and then split the properties ',' .

ex: Address,Status,CheckDate,Ping|Address,Status,CheckDate,Ping|...etc

But that way I don't know how I would go about updating the list... Would I reread the whole string from the db? I just don't know how to go about this. I haven't tried this way because of the updating part, removing bad proxies or grabbing unchecked proxies.

- I've added custom properties to the user's IdentityModel & updated the database.

  ### - Added: ProxiesAsString nvarchar(max)

Here are some pictures that may be useful to understanding what I'm doing:
[Proxy Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz84s.png)

Please help me ask questions because I really don't know how to ask questions about this type of thing.

Comment: Pictures aren't useful. Code is though.

Comment: Read [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates/) and see how they are adding `MyUserInfo` to the identity model. You can add your `Proxy` class like that.

Comment: I want to know how to add a list to a database